# Static files are not loading after deployment on digitelocean

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, django-deployment

I have deploye my django application on digitel ocean by following this

> blog:alocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04

this is the url as an error i am getting in console for static files

> (index):5913 GET http://67.205.160.21/static/js/dashkit.min.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) (index):5913 GET
> http://67.205.160.21/static/js/style.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
> (Forbidden)

every thing is fine except static file,

**settings.py**

```
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

after running the python3 manage.py collect static it gives this

> /home/podstatsclub/webapp/Podcast_stats/static

which i have put into default.config file which look something like this

> ```
>     Alias /static /home/podstatsclub/webapp/Podcast_stats/static
>     <Directory /home/podstatsclub/webapp/Podcast_stats/static>
>             <Files wsgi.py>
>               Require all granted
>             </Files>
>     </Directory>
>
>     <Directory /home/podstatsclub/webapp/Podcast_stats/podcast>
>       <Files wsgi.py>
>         Require all granted
>       </Files>
>     </Directory>
>
>     WSGIDaemonProcess Podcast_stats python-home=/home/podstatsclub/webapp/Podcast_stats/env pytho>
>     WSGIProcessGroup Podcast_stats
>     WSGIScriptAlias / /home/podstatsclub/webapp/Podcast_stats/podcast/wsgi.py
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your static directory you accidentally grant access only to wsgi.py ... thats a copy paste mistake. Just leave the "require all granted" there.

Comment: emm i have write this something like this    <Directory /home/podstatsclub/webapp/Podcast_stats/static>
            <Files wsgi.py>
              Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

Comment: i mean  add the Require all granted after the <files> tag

Comment: owh great man thank you very much brother you don't know you becomes like angel bundles of love and great wished for you